# Accessing Docker-compose containers hostnames from a container

Tags: python, docker, containers, docker-compose, hostname

I'm trying to setup an app that works as a Peer Sampling Service. Each peer would run on a separate container and for ease of use I'd have one tracker that would give to each peer its initial view.

For the tracker I'm running it as a Python 3.5 web server that has a simple REST API. when contacted it calls `docker-compose -H tcp://hostip:2375 ps` to get the list of containers and their hostnames.

Strangely though when this container executes this command, the docker daemon answers with an empty list, whereas if I ask this daemon not from the container but from my computer or even from an other computer on the same local network it works fine.

I have no idea why the daemon would send two different results.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.5.1

# RUN pip install pydevd

ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code

EXPOSE 4321

RUN echo 'starting Tracker'
CMD [ "python", "./scripts/tracker.py" ]
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  pss:
    build: .
  tracker:
    expose:
      - "4321"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-tracker
```

and the line in the python file :
`ps_output = subprocess.check_output('docker-compose -H tcp://<daemon_host_ip>:2375 ps', shell=True).decode().splitlines()`

Comment: What is the output if you run the command itself in the container, outside of python. Any error output?

Comment: Yeah, no error output.

Comment: Is the output from `docker -H tcp://<daemon_host_ip>:2375 info` identical (using your host ip) from inside and outside the container?

Comment: They are identical. I tried mounting docker.sock in the container instead of going the tcp://... way and it didn't help either.